# Can I read the text from an exe file in c?

Tags: c, pipe

I have two games I created in c:

The first is a guess the number game: the computer chooses a number and the user has to guess it.

The second does the opposite: the user chooses a number and the computer has to guess it through feedback from the user (h or l)

Now I want to make the two programs *play with each other*. for example: I open the two programs and the first takes an input from the second and then provides the value to it.

I have found that it is possible to do this indirectly using a text file:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<unistd.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>


 int main()
 { 
   char line[260]
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("file.txt", "r+");
   if(fr == NULL){ printf("File not found");}
   fscanf("%s", line);

     fclose(fr);
    return 0;
   }
```

And I would use sleep to make sure the program reads the correct data. But I don't like this way: I will have to view the results after the game is over. Is there a way I can make this work: like seeing the results while the game is on? Is it possible to read and write to an .exe file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interaction of two c/c++ programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13103411/interaction-of-two-c-c-programs)

Comment: just google for IPC, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Comment: @DCoder they are both written in c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to connect both programs by two pipes. There is plenty of examples creating two pipes and forking a subprocess. You may want to have a look on the function `popen` and also `popen2` for bidirectional communication which was presented for example
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778672/killing-process-that-has-been-created-with-popen2).

Comment: @neomhmd Yes. All those functions are in C.